# Creating a port between content script and browser action javascript in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, port

In order to detect when the browser action closes in a Chrome Extension, I'm creating a connection between the browser action javascript and the background script, and using `port.onDisconnect`. I then alert a tab's content script of the closing using `tabs.sendMessage`. Is there any way that I can create a port between the content script and browser action javascript to remove the need for a background page?

Comment: Not sure it wasn't asked before, but I'd probably send a dummy message every 100ms, for example, to the content script from the popup. In the content script a SetTimeout with alert inside would be reset every time this message arrives. So when it doesn't, you know the popup was closed.

Comment: There isn't a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Try sending a message from `window.onbeforeunload` in the popup.

Comment: Have you tried directly moving the establishing connection logic to content scripts? I mean directly communicating between content script and popup page. The logic is same as between background page and popup page.

Comment: @HaibaraAi I don't know how to do that. I think the code may be different, but I'm unsure.